# Express-generator, Socket.io Event issuing multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I have create a node app using express generator. I have integrated socket.io in the application. Since express generator has their own way of creating express server i have followed [this procedure](https://onedesigncompany.com/news/express-generator-and-socket-io) to successfully integrate the Socket connection with listening server and made the io available throughout the application via res.io instance.

FILE: **bin/www**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var app = require('../app').app;
var debug = require('debug')('www:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = require('../app').server;
```

**/app.js**

```
//Express handler
var app = express();
// Socket configuration
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.io = io;
  next();
});

...

module.exports = {app: app, server: server};
```

But the problem is when i m emitting an event as shown below. My client is reading the data multiple times.

**routes/index.js**

```
   var clients = 0;
   var nsp = res.io.of('/default-namespace');
    nsp.on('connection', function (socket) {
      clients++;
      console.log(clients + ' clients connected!');
      socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
        clients--;
        console.log(clients + ' clients connected!');
      });
         nsp.emit("socketToMe", "New User connected. Current clients:"+ clients);
    });
```

My listener has the following code:
**home.pug**

```
 var socket = io('/default-namespace');
 socket.on('socketToMe', function (data) {
    $('#data-div').append($('<li>').text(data));
    });
```

Whenever i refresh the browser in another instance like incoginito my main browser is showing multiple events for the data. Like this

```
New User connected. Current clients:1
New User connected. Current clients:2
New User connected. Current clients:1
New User connected. Current clients:2
New User connected. Current clients:1
New User connected. Current clients:1
```

Not sure what is wrong. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejs is event driven.The **res** object is not a global variable.
Express middleware runs for every request.

```
   var clients = 0;
   var nsp = res.io.of('/default-namespace');
   nsp.on('connection', function (socket) {
     clients++;
     console.log(clients + ' clients connected!');
     socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
     clients--;
     console.log(clients + ' clients connected!');
     });
     nsp.emit("socketToMe", "New User connected. Current 
     clients:"+clients);
   });
```

Let me explain what happens above.A user requests and **req** handler is fired and you access the **res** object and you listen for events.
So for each request, you are listening for socket **'connection'** event.That means you are setting **multiple event listeners** with the same name.Every time you make a request you set a **new listener**.

You are supposed to set only a **single** 'connection' listener.

*This explains emitting the same event multiple times.*

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
 res.io = io;
 next();
});
```

Instead of using the above middleware function,listen directly on **io** instance

Comment: Worked perfectly. Instead of adding a
  nsp.on('connection'  
,  i m simply emitting on nsp.emit